# rsync: No space left on device, although plenty of space available

Tags: usb, backup, rsync

When doing a backup with `rscync` to a USB stick, I sometimes get for one or another file the error message

```
rsync: [receiver] write failed on (FILENAME) : No space left on device (28)
rsync: [sender] write error: Connection reset by peer (104)
```

I'm using the command

```
rsync -ra -T /tmp --delete FROM_DIR TO_DIR  --info=del
```

This is weird, because the USB stick has a reported capacity of 235 GB, of which 79 GB are available. The data being backed up has a total size of about 100 GB, and each individual file is below 300 MB, most of them about 3-5 MB. During the backup process, most of the files have not changed between the original and the backup; just a few dozen ones actually need an update, but of course it could be that rsync always writes all files in this scenario (since the backup is not done over the network).

Can this type of error messages be explained with my settings, or do I have to assume that the USB stick is faulty?

**UPDATE** :

The source for the backup is on an external hard disk (i.e. rsync copies some of the directories from one external disk to the backup device).

The errors occur only when the backup device is this particular  USB-stick. When I use for the backup another external hard disk (which has much more free space), there is never a write error.

Since all other parameters are the same (source disk, disk for temporary files), the only "real" difference is that the device which causes less problems, happens to be a USB device, and it has much less free space than the other backup devices (hard disks, SSD).

I would like to find out if the amount of free space in the USB-stick could be the explanation for the error (and why), or if I need to assume that the USB stick is faulty (how can I check this?).

**UPDATE 2**:

I did the following rudimentary checks for the quality of the USB-stick:

1. Running the Windows utility `CHKDSK ... /r`
2. Running the external utility [FakeFlashTest](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/image/21414.html) in the non-destructive mode. In this mode, it calculates the free space as reported by the USB drive (which roughly matches the one I got before), and then creates a a file of exactly this size, thereby filling up the drive.

Both tests went well without error. From this, I tend to conclude that there is something in the way `rsync` is operating, which makes it necessary to have much more space at the destination drive available than a single file would occupy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
[rsync : write failed - No space left on device (28)](https://serverfault.com/a/861807/18736) :

> I had the same issue, the destination directory had enough space but
> I'd get "No space left on device". Turns out rsync copies the file to
> somewhere else first, then moves it to the destination directory. To
> change this behavior, use `--inplace`.
>
> According to https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html "This
> option changes how rsync transfers a file when its data needs to be
> updated: instead of the default method of creating a new copy of the
> file and moving it into place when it is complete, rsync instead
> writes the updated data directly to the destination file."
>
> ```
>  rsync --inplace source destination
> ```

A pity that the developers of rsync didn't include the partition name
in the message. Many users of rsync were stymied by this very vague
message.

Comment: I don't think this applies to my case. This would matter if a single file would be transfered whose size is larger or equal of the free space in the destination directory. However even the largest file to be copied occupies much less than 1% of the free space.

Comment: The free space on which disk? The rsync destination?

Comment: Correct. The source (an external hard drive) has more than one TB available. The local disk (which is referred to by the `-T` option of `rsync`), is pretty full, but nevertheless still has more than 4 GB available, which should be sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: You should rather check the free space of the disk where temporary files are stored. You could also try `rsync --inplace` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: If this were the culprit, the error would occur no matter what destination device I plug in. I will update the question with this point.

Comment: I'm saying that this isn't because of the destination disk, but of the temporary-files disk, which might be `/tmp`.

Comment: I understand this. But if this would be the reason, replacing the USB stick by another external device would still make the error to occur. Since this does not happen, I would conclude that the local file space is not the problem.

Comment: You should have said that it doesn't happen with another USB device. In this case something is wrong with this one.

Comment: That's why I now updated my question. You made me aware that this information is important. But if you also think, that the amount of free space on the stick can't be the reason, I also fear that the stick (it is a new one!) has some hardware flaws.

Comment: There have been several posts on our site where the space on the external disk was plain wrong. Usually it's smaller than the rated capacity, but in your case it might be larger. Some cases could be fixed with updating the disk's firmware and some not. Check if the disk manufacturer has such a utility, you could also try to reformat the disk, check the SMART attributes of the disk (if it has it)),  but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: May I ask you to have a look at my last update to my question? I think that as a next step I will try out the `--inplace`  option you suggested earlier, although I can see a logical reason why this should help in my particular case, given the file sizes I'm going to transfer.

Comment: You could try `--inplace`. I don't have more suggestions.

Comment: `--inplace` indeed fixed the problem. From this, I conclude that rsync does not copy file by file, but first copies everything to a some space on the destination volume, and then renames is. This means that the free space must be at least as large as the whole amount of data to be copied,